# How can I automatically run a script inside screen if the script is not in $PATH

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a scenario where I need to cd into a directory before running a script:

```
cd repos; python script.py
```

But it should be setup such that it automatically runs when screen is started. So in `.screenrc` I have this:

```
screen -t "cd repos; python script.py"
```

except this doesn't work because the `cd repos` is wrong. How do I cd into this directory?

Comment: Why don't you use absolute path to "repos" dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to happen by default when you run screen, then you'll need to edit your ***.screenrc*** file.  You can use the ***chdir*** directive to have a new screen window change directories upon opening it, but you'll want to explicitly reset that after your needs are met, so that newer windows are not affected.

```
# .screenrc settings to cd to repos and run python-script.py
chdir /full/path/to/repos
screen -t "Python Script" ./python-script.py

# reset the default directory for new windows.
chdir $HOME
screen -t "New Window" bash
screen -t "SSH Session" ssh foo@bar.com
```

Keep in mind that this will essentially set "./python-script.py" as the shell for that window, so when python-script.py is finished the window will close.

Answer (score 1):

The option `-t` is for the title, so is wrong in your context.

I would write

```
screen sh -c 'cd repos; python script.py'
```

Some observations:

1. a correctly setup application should not depend on the working directory to work properly, so `screen python repos/script.py` should work as well (not taking into account that the same explicit invokation of `python` could be avoided)
2. if you put that into `~/.screenrc`, the command will be executed on each new screen invokation. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: I agree 100% with observation #1.  Fix that and this question would have never come up.